# C - malloc/realloc and dynamic strings

Tags: c, string, malloc, realloc

I've been practicing some pointer concepts so I can fully grasp how to use them. I'm working on a scanner/parser for JSON files in C as practice. The first step is to check character by character and confirm it's a character I want to keep. {, }, and : are all ignored; at least for extracting them.

The idea is to read in character by character and keep count of the size, and to append this to a string. I've got a simple program that prints out a name. I haven't added the free yet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stringBuilder(char c, int size, char *Strng)
{
    int arryPosit=size-1;
    Strng[arryPosit]=c;

    return Strng;
}

int main() {
    char c1 = 'J';
    char c2= 'o';
    char c3 = 's';
    char c4= 'h';
    char c5= '\n';
    char *myString=NULL;

    myString= (char *) malloc(1* sizeof(char));

    myString = stringBuilder(c1,1,myString);
    myString= (char *) realloc(myString, 2* sizeof(char));

    myString = stringBuilder(c2,2,myString);
    myString= (char *) realloc(myString, 3* sizeof(char));

    myString = stringBuilder(c3,3,myString);
    myString= (char *) realloc(myString, 4* sizeof(char));

    myString = stringBuilder(c4,4,myString);
    myString= (char *) realloc(myString, 5* sizeof(char));

    myString = stringBuilder(c5,5,myString);

    printf(myString);
    free(myString);
}
```

The idea is to dynamically allocate and reallocate memory as new characters come in. This is a simple proof of concept I wrote. While it works, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. The reason I'm reallocating, at least in my head, is because the strings I'll be working with could be 15 characters, or 4. I don't want to over allocate memory; but I am new to using pointers correctly. Is this concept on the right track, is there another way or something I might be missing?

See comments for answer.

Comment: I wouldn't do this.  Just do a single allocation for the largest string you expect.

Comment: Whats the `char sub[700];` for?

Comment: If this should become more than an exercise, I would rather preallocate a reasonable sized string. allocation is expensive, so in a real world parser, this would mean bad performance. If a string is bigger than your assumed size, you still can reallocate. My personal rule: Avoid allocations wherever possible.

Comment: ```sub[700];``` was old code I forgot to remove. Devolus, thank you for the explanation. So it would be a serious performance hit, which is good enough for me. Thank you all for input; I'll allocate the largest I'd expect.

Comment: If you absolutely must allocate memory at run time, you can calculate the length of the string before allocating it and then assign the value instead of lengthening the array with every input character. Just a thought.

Comment: You list `{}:` as characters to ignore — you're likely to need to ignore `[],` too — at least until you start verifying that the JSON is well-formed, at which point all of those characters become important.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the recommendation. I'm actually trying to build a parser that can convert JSON into a schema; specifically poorly formed. It's a problem I'm running into in my job; and so on the side I'm seeing how likely it is to solve it. I'm not sure how possible it is, but it's a fun project and it'll help me learn more C